# Collect text from loop

Tags: python, loops

I import CSV file and run by loop for result.
I would like to collect result from loop but i got only last line.

For example

test.csv contains

```
sentence1
sentence2
sentence3
```

```
with codecs.open('test.csv', 'r','utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        test = f.readlines()

for t in test:
    text = strip_all_entities(strip_links(t)) #cleaning sentence
    result = (text+" : "+ "test")
```

I want :-

```
sentence1 : test
sentence2 : test
sentence3 : test
```

but it showed only last sentence :-

```
sentence3 : test
```

How can I fix this code?

Comment: `result = [strip_all_entities(strip_links(t)) for t in test]` And then, iterate over `result` and print.

Comment: You overwrite `result` when processing each next line. So `result` will only hold the actual results of the last line.

Comment: Thanks COLDSPEED, I would like to add some text (e.g in code "test") for each sentence and save in result.

Comment: Thanks usr2564301, So How can I collect result for each line ?

Comment: @ZayajungC By appending them to a list?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you should do differently.

Firstly, `readlines()` returns an array of strings with the length being equal to the amount of lines in your file. That means you don't actually have to loop over all the lines and call `readlines()` for each of them. Instead, just call it once:

```
with codecs.open('test.csv', 'r','utf-8') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
```

Secondly, if you're just doing `result = something`, all the previous entries in result get overridden, which is the reason why you are only seeing one line. Try the following:

```
results = []
for line in lines:
   results.append(strip_all_entities(strip_links(lines)) + " : " + "Test")
```

See [this link](http://stackabuse.com/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/) for a more detailed introduction to python readlines.